# Show Google Maps panorama street view in panel when marker clicked

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I have a huge list of markers plotted on a Google Map.  When a marker is clicked an info window is opened.  I'd also like to load a street view panorama in a div over the map at this point, showing the location of the marker that was clicked.

I have a basic implementation of the street view working in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ETTP4/.  This is pretty much what I want it to do; when you click the marker the info window loads and a separate panel loads the streetview.

However, when I try to incorporate this into my implementation with many markers, I can't seem to get it to load the streetview with the correct location.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/uP56p/.

I think the reason for my second example failing is because the panorama is being set on the DOM load map event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
```

Presumably this needs instead to become part of the marker click event.  However, having tried this I just can't get it to work, and I'm also not sure about performance in doing this, since there are likely to be over 100 markers.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

Many thanks.